# Issue with require.js when adding web3.js to project

Tags: dependencies, requirejs, web3js

When adding the web3.js cdn my index.html, I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function

This only occurs when I include the web3.js script. Below is what I put in index.html (I've been using the [getting-started](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#getting-started) guide as a reference).

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script>
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
          web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
          // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
          web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
          console.log(web3);
      }
</script>
```

In the debugger I see that web3 properly loads before the error. Could really use advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Requirejs will not know cdn path to load web3, you could add config for requirejs and load using require or define,

for example

```
     requirejs.config({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: { 
        /* Load from google cdn. On fail, load local file. */
        'web3': ['//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"', 'web3.min']

    }

});

require(['web3'], function(web3) {
    console.log("Loaded :)");    
    return {};
});
```